# ListView Scrolling when Item Added to Collection on one machine but not another

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, scroll

I have an WPF app using MVVM that shows a log in a ListView control. I have it bound to an ObservableCollection and the control updates when items are added.

I have it coded so that when it starts, it automatically scrolls to the top when an item is inserted into the collection at position 0 so it always shows the latest log message. This works on all machines I have tested.

When a user does something on the ListView (clicks or scrolls), the automatic scrolling is turned off so the user can look at any part of the log they want. When they are finished looking at the log, they can click a button to turn the automatic scrolling back on. Everything works except on one of my test machines, the view changes as items are added. On my dev machine and another test machine, the ListView window does not change when things are added to the collection. Same code/config files are used for all systems.

For example:

- The user scrolls to show "My Item" at the top of the ListView.
- Another log message is added.
- I want "My Item" to still show at the top of the ListView.

Dev machine and one Test machine: "My Item" shows at the top of the ListView.
Another Test Machine: "My Item" is now in the second row of the ListView.

The original change request was because this scrolling was not working on some machines but not others. After much time, there seems to be a difference in the machines themselves that is effecting this.

Is there some system setting that would control this?

XAML:

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="9" Name="messagesListView"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  Margin="8,0,40,0"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StatusMessagesList}"
              SelectionChanged="messagesListView_SelectionChanged"
              PreviewMouseWheel="messagesListView_PreviewMouseWheel"
              MouseDoubleClick="batchesListView_MouseDoubleClick"
              PreviewMouseDown="messagesListView_MouseDown"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        </ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
        private void ScrollToTop()
        {
            scrollPos = 0;
            ScrollSpot.Text = scrollPos.ToString();
            ScrollToPos();
        }
        private void ScrollToPos()
        {
            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(messagesListView) as ScrollViewer;
            if (scrollViewer != null && _viewState)
                scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollPos);
        }

        private void autoScrollButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            messagesListView.SelectedItem = null;
            autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            _viewState = true;
            ScrollToTop();
        }
        private void ListBox_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(messagesListView) as ScrollViewer;
                if (scrollViewer != null && _viewState)
                {
                    ScrollToTop();
                }
                if(scrollViewer != null && !_viewState)
                {
                    scrollPos += e.NewItems.Count;
                    ScrollSpot.Text = scrollPos.ToString();
                    ScrollToPos();
                }
            }
        }

        private void messagesListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewState = false;
            autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void messagesListView_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewState = false;
            autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void messagesListView_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            _viewState = false;
            autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        private void messagesListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource.GetType().ToString().IndexOf("Rectangle") >= 0)
            {
                _viewState = false;
                autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

Code to Add to Collection:

```
                {
                    if (_statusMessagesList == null)
                        StatusMessagesList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                    string stMsg = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), message);
                    StatusMessagesList.Insert(0, stMsg);
```

Thanks,
Brad P.

Comment: Put some code to see what you are doing. This type of posts, without showing what you have done, are downvoted quickly..

Comment: Updated the OP to add code. This even inlcludes trying to save the scroll position, add to it the number of new items, and then scroll to the new position and that does not even work.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I never found out why one system worked and the other did not. However, the solution I found that worked on both was to set `messagesListView.CanContentScroll = False`
and then manually keep track of the Offset Position on the ScrollViewer:

```
        {
            SetUpManualScroll(0);
        }

        private void messagesListView_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
        {
            double scrollAmt = (e.Delta / 120) * -48;
            SetUpManualScroll(scrollAmt);
        }

        private void messagesListView_Scroll(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            
            SetUpManualScroll(e.NewValue);
        }
        private void messagesListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SetUpManualScroll(0);
        }

        private void messagesListView_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.OriginalSource.GetType().ToString().IndexOf("TextBlock") < 0 && e.OriginalSource.GetType().ToString().IndexOf("Border") < 0)
            {
                if (_scrollviewer.VerticalOffset != 0)
                    SetUpManualScroll(0);
                else
                {
                    messagesListView.SelectedItem = null;
                    autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                    _viewState = true;
                    ScrollToTop();
                }
            }
        }
        private void SetUpManualScroll(double d)
        {
            _viewState = false;
            autoScrollButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            _scrollviewer.UpdateLayout();
            double newPos = _scrollviewer.VerticalOffset + d;
            if (newPos < 0)
                newPos = 0;
            ScrollPos = newPos;
        }

        private void ScrollToTop()
        {
            ScrollPos = 0;
            ScrollToPos();
        }
        private void ScrollToPos()
        {
            if (_scrollviewer == null)
            {
                _scrollviewer = GetScrollViewer(messagesListView);
            }

            _scrollviewer.UpdateLayout();
            _scrollviewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollPos);
        }
```